# Display a different user's information in a profile (Not the logged in user's)

Tags: python, html, django

I'm working on a project for school, it's sort of *mini-stackoverflow.* So, I have a section where users are able to click on the creator of a post, and it'll take then to a page where they can see said user's information and all the posts they have created. So, so far the code for the user posts list is perfect but I can't get the profile information to be displayed correctly.

To explain the problem in a more simple way, it's basically that, if I click on winston1420's profile instead shows me a different profile (of the logged in user)

**My profile on HTML template**

```
<section class="py-5">
        <div class="container my-5">
            <div class="row justify-content">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="content-section">
                        <div class="media">
                          <img class="rounded-circle profile-img" src="{{ user.profile.image.url }}"/>
                          <div class="media-body">
                            <h2 class="account-heading">{{ view.kwargs.username }}</h2>
                            <p class="text-secondary">{{ user.first_name }} {{ user.last_name }}</p>
                            <p class="text-secondary">{{ user.email }}</p>
                            <div class="container">
                               <p class="lead"><Strong>Sobre mi:</strong></p>
                               <p class="lead">{{ user.description }}</p>
                            </div>
                            <br>
                            <p class="text-secondary">Se unió el {{ user.date_joined }}</p>
                            <p class="text-secondary">Última vez visto: {{ user.last_login }}</p>
                            <p class="mb-0">{{ user.profile.about }}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**My user's post list**

```
<div class="container my-5">
            <div class="row justify-content">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <h2>Publicaciones de <strong><a href="">{{ view.kwargs.username }}</a></strong> ({{ page_obj.paginator.count }}) </h2>
                    <br>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% for post in posts%}
                <article class="media post-content-section">
                    <img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{ post.author.profile.image.url }}">
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <div class="article-metadata">
                        <a class="mr-2" href="{% url 'user-posts' post.author.username %}">{{ post.author }}</a>
                        <small class="text-muted">{{ post.date_posted|date:"j / m / Y" }}</small>
                        </div>
                        <h2><a class="article-title" href="{% url 'post-detail' post.id %}">{{ post.titulo }}</a></h2>
                        <!-- <p class="article-content">{{ post.contenido }}</p> -->
                    </div>
                </article>
            {% endfor %}
            <br>
            {% if is_paginated %}
                <Center>{% if page_obj.has_previous %}
                    <a class="btn btn-outlife-info mb-4" href="?page=1">Primera Página</a>
                    <a class="btn btn-outlife-info mb-4" href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">Página Anterior</a>
                {% endif %}
                {% for num in page_obj.paginator.page_range %}
                    {% if page_obj.number == num %}
                        <a class="btn btn-info mb-4" href="?page={{ num }}">{{ num }}</a>
                    {% elif num > page_obj.number|add:'-3' and num < page_obj.number|add:'3' %}
                        <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{ num }}">{{ num }}</a>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
                {% if page_obj.has_next %}
                    <a class="btn btn-outlife-info mb-4" href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">Siguiente Página</a>
                    <a class="btn btn-outlife-info mb-4" href="?page={{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}">Última Página</a>
                {% endif %}</center>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
```

**User Views**

```
@login_required
def profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user) 
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)

        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'¡Tu perfil se ha actualizado correctamente!')
            return redirect('profile')


    else:
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)

    context = {
        'u_form': u_form,
        'p_form': p_form
    }

    return render(request, 'users/profile.html', context)
```

**Post list Views**

```
class PostListView(ListView):
model = Post
template_name = 'forum/forum_main.html'
context_object_name = 'posts'
ordering = ['-date_posted']
paginate_by = 5


class UserPostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'forum/user_posts.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 5

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
        return Post.objects.filter(author=user).order_by('-date_posted')
```

So, as you guys can see, for the post list I was using **kwargs** but I can't do the same for the profile, aside from the username which I already did. How can I do it?

Tips or links to documentation are appreciated as well.

Here is an image for reference:

Comment: provide views related to it

Comment: @AnkitTiwari Alright, I have added the views to my post.